# Delete leading and trailing spaces in DAX Power Query

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

I am looking for SQL equivalent of `ltrim(rtrim(text))`

Is it the same as DAX: [TRIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/trim-function-dax) function or M function: [Text.Trim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/text-trim) ?

Comment: DAX and Power Query are 2 different languages. Text.Trim is Power Query, your link points to DAX.

Why would SQL ltrim(rtrim(text) remove excessive spaces?

Comment: @MarcelBeug I removed excessive spaces from my question. I will be happy to know how to remove leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: I actually don't see a question. For power query, as you stated, you can use the Text.Trim option. For DAX the statement is TRIM()

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634558.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Dax use the following measures (works in columns the same):

```
Measure 0:=" A column with spaces. "
Measure 1:=TRIM([Measure 0])
```

Check lengths of both fields:

```
Len 0:=len([measure 0])
Len 1:=len([Measure 1])
```

Results: 
Len 0: 23
Len 1: 21

[image]

Answer (score 3):

DAX function - quote from documentation - "Removes all spaces from text **except for single spaces between words**".

Power Query Text.Trim by default removes all leading and trailing whitespaces. Alteratively you can provide a second argument with one or more (in a list) characters that must be trimmed.

You can find more information about Power Query Text.Trim and whitespaces in this video (with some additional links below the video)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g3ws234FRes